# Are intermediate bulk container units suitable for storage of isopropyl alcohol?

Tags: polymers, alcohols, safety, reactivity, plastics

I'm working in water treatment construction and my boss is going to be stocking isopropyl alcohol (IPA).

He wants to store the chemical in bulk, with amounts ranging from 5000 L to 10000 L in [IBC units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_bulk_container).

Is storage of IPA in plastic containers okay? Will the chemical react with plastic?

Comment: What type of [plastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic) and storing conditions (most importantly, temperature, exposure to light and ambient polluting factors)? Caged IBC units are typically HDPE and should be suitable for IPA, but you might want to double-check with the supplier just in case they use something else or have additives/stabilizers in IPA.

Comment: You should have a discussion with your friendly local fire protection engineer. They may have issues with 10000 liters of isopropyl alcohol suddenly appearing on site.

Comment: Is there any legislation that can back this up?

Comment: @ImranMunir - legislation on what, exactly? Check with the IPA supplier for what containers they can ship in. Check with fire protection for how those containers need to be stored so your facility doesn't burn down too readily.

Answer (score 2):

The volume makes this a non-trivial question like "what plastic resists IPA". As commented , there are fire protection concerns, maybe a berm will be required. Likely the answer is steel, possible with internal coating. There are strength considerations handled by steel; I think it will be difficult to find creep/long term strain, allowable stress values for a plastic vessel. When designing for low pressure plastic (FRP) water pipe, my company had to do extensive testing to determine allowable strength. The manufacturers had only estimated at strength levels; not adequate for storing significant amounts of flammable liquid.

Answer (score -2):

If plastic is PE it will be fine. Most large plastic containers for chemicals are PE.

PP will also be fine, but it is usually for rigid boxes.

[an article with a solvent compatibility table](https://www.terrauniversal.com/blog/chemical-compatibility-chart-plastics/) , because people here dont like images

Comment: I suppose you forgot to cite the source of the data, which is also a bit too excessive for what OP is about (single solvent).

Comment: Citing is not putting in an obfuscated link of where you found an image. It is giving credit to those who have produced this content. This is at least, but not limited to, including a clear text link of the source and authors where available. Apart from this, please make sure that you are allowed to use the image on [chemistry.se].